# How to list all movies staring ​Jeff Goldblum but not ​Bruce Willis'?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My model has 3 tables: **ACTORS**, **MOVIES** and **MOVIE_CAST**, which represents the relationship between ACTORS and MOVIES.

Table: ACTORS

- Columns: Name, Birth_Year
- Primary Key: Name, Birth_Year

Table: Movies

- Columns: Title, Release_Year, Genre, Director
- Primary Key: Title, Release_Year

Table: MOVIE_CAST

- Columns: Movie (FK), Movie_Release_Year (FK), Actor (FK), Birth_Yearh (FK)

---

**I need to list the title, release year, genre and director of all movies staring ​'Jeff Goldblum' but NOT ​'Bruce Willis'​.**

I've tried the query below but it's not working. It returns me all the movies that ​Jeff Goldblum starred, including the ones he did with Bruce Willis.

```
SELECT A.NAME, M.TITLE, M.RELEASE_YEAR, M.GENRE, M.DIRECTOR
FROM ACTORS A
    JOIN MOVIE_CAST MC ON A.NAME = MC.ACTOR AND A.BIRTH_YEAR = MC.BIRTH_YEAR
    JOIN MOVIES M ON M.TITLE = MC.MOVIE AND M.RELEASE_YEAR = MC.MOVIE_RELEASE_YEAR
WHERE A.NAME = 'Jeff Goldblum' AND A.NAME != 'Bruce Willis'
```

How can I write the query to return me the movies that Jeff Goldblum starred alone or with other actors, except Bruce Willis?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to aggregate by movie (and its metadata) and then assert that Jeff Goldblum be present and Bruce Willis not be present:

```
SELECT M.TITLE, M.RELEASE_YEAR, M.GENRE, M.DIRECTOR
FROM ACTORS A
INNER JOIN MOVIE_CAST MC ON A.NAME = MC.ACTOR AND A.BIRTH_YEAR = MC.BIRTH_YEAR
INNER JOIN MOVIES M ON M.TITLE = MC.MOVIE AND M.RELEASE_YEAR = MC.MOVIE_RELEASE_YEAR
GROUP BY M.TITLE, M.RELEASE_YEAR, M.GENRE, M.DIRECTOR
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN A.NAME = 'Jeff Goldblum' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND  -- Goldblum appears
    COUNT(CASE WHEN A.NAME = 'Bruce Willis' THEN 1 END) = 0;      -- but not Willis
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `not exists` condition to filter out the movies staring Bruce Willis:

```sql
SELECT A.NAME, M.TITLE, M.RELEASE_YEAR, M.GENRE, M.DIRECTOR
FROM   ACTORS A
JOIN   MOVIE_CAST MC ON A.NAME = MC.ACTOR AND A.BIRTH_YEAR = MC.BIRTH_YEAR
JOIN   MOVIES M ON M.TITLE = MC.MOVIE AND M.RELEASE_YEAR = MC.MOVIE_RELEASE_YEAR
WHERE  A.NAME = 'Jeff Goldblum' AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   ACTORS b
                   WHERE  b.NAME = MC.ACTOR AND 
                          b.BIRTH_YEAR = MC.BIRTH_YEAR AND
                          b.NAME = 'Bruce Willis')
```

Comment: I've tried that and this is still returning me the movies that Bruce Willies starred along with Jeff Goldblum

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered the **EXCEPT** statement (which is the MINUS statement depending on the database used).

So my query became:

```
SELECT M.TITLE, M.RELEASE_YEAR, M.GENRE, M.DIRECTOR
FROM   ACTORS A
    JOIN   MOVIE_CAST MC ON A.NAME = MC.ACTOR AND A.BIRTH_YEAR = MC.BIRTH_YEAR
    JOIN   MOVIES M ON M.TITLE = MC.MOVIE AND M.RELEASE_YEAR = MC.MOVIE_RELEASE_YEAR
WHERE  A.NAME = 'Jeff Goldblum' 

EXCEPT

SELECT M.TITLE, M.RELEASE_YEAR, M.GENRE, M.DIRECTOR
FROM   ACTORS A
    JOIN   MOVIE_CAST MC ON A.NAME = MC.ACTOR AND A.BIRTH_YEAR = MC.BIRTH_YEAR
    JOIN   MOVIES M ON M.TITLE = MC.MOVIE AND M.RELEASE_YEAR = MC.MOVIE_RELEASE_YEAR
WHERE  A.NAME = 'Bruce Willis'
```

And it worked!

Comment: This requires executing two queries, and therefore may not be as efficient as the other two answers.